# How to bind function on different buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to bind alert on my buttons:

```
for(var i=1; i<=3; i++){
   $('#' + i).live('click', function(){
       alert(i);
   });
};
```

It is my html code:

```
<input id="1" type="button" value="one">
<input id="2" type="button" value="two">
<input id="3" type="button" value="three">
```

But I get 4 on all buttons. How to fix it to get correctly alert values? (1, 2, 3 and etc..)

http://jsfiddle.net/sergey1986/UFjsM/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    $('#' + i).live('click', function(i) {
        return function() {
            alert(i);
        };
    }(i));
}
```

Note that you are using `.live` wrong, the point is not to bind to each element individually, but to figure out what each element have in common and use that selector:

```
$("input[type=button]").live(function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this.id, as when loop is finished i will have the last value which break the loop.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UFjsM/1/)**

```
for(var i=1; i<=3; i++){
   $('#' + i).live('click', function(){
       alert(this.id);
   });
};
```

Its better to give some common class to all the button and use that class to bind the event.

```
<input id="1" type="button" value="one" class="someclass">
<input id="2" type="button" value="two" class="someclass">
<input id="3" type="button" value="three" class="someclass">

$('.someclass').live('click', function(){
   alert(this.id);
});
```

live is deprecated you better use [**on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('.someclass').on('click', function(){
   alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Ok, but how to bind without use of id of button?

Comment: give some common class to all buttons $('.someclas').live('click', function(){
       alert(i);
   });

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple:

```
for(var i=1; i<=3; i++){
   $('#' + i).live('click', function(){
       alert(this.id);
   });
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rzpXK/

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things that are (although not *wrong* per se) not very good practices.

1. An element's `id` should not begin with numbers
2. `.live()` is deprecated and should be avoided. `.on()` should be used instead
3. `.live()` or `.on()` should not be bound like that in a loop. They should be done in one shot, using a single selector where possible.
4. Use of a common `class` for all your buttons is a better idea if you want the same event to be bound to multiple elements

Try

```
$('input[type=button]').on('click', function(){
   alert( this.id );
})
```